# Error: Either “offers”, “review”, or “aggregateRating” should be specified, in google search console

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, google-search-console

Iam using woocommerce in my wordpress site. The Products report was added to search console in late February, and with it came an abundance of warnings and an error titled: Either “offers”, “review”, or “aggregateRating” should be specified. 
The Products report can be found under the enhancements section in Google Search Console. what are the causes of this error?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Yoast, I will recommend you to disable the Schema for Yoast in general but remember that if you are using blog section then it will hurt your blog.

Following code will disable the Yoast 11+ Schema. Put that in functions.php of your theme or child theme.

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_json_ld_output', '__return_false' );
```

And following code works for earlier versions of yoast.

```
function disable_yoast_schema_data($data){
    $data = array();
    return $data;
}
add_filter('wpseo_json_ld_output', 'disable_yoast_schema_data', 10, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

product Schema is possibly the cause of these errors, please try adding this to your functions

```
/**
 * Remove the generated product schema markup from Product Category and Shop pages.
 */
function wc_remove_product_schema() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop', array( WC()->structured_data, 'generate_product_data' ), 10, 0 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'wc_remove_product_schema' );
```

Update

As you say you are using yoast i would look into the specific yoast woocoommerce plugin and the plugin docs to add the correct schema

https://developer.yoast.com/schema-documentation/woocommerce-seo/

Comment: the schema is generated from yoast seo plugin. How can i disable yoast plugin generated json-ld schema only in product category and shop pages? Any idea ?

Comment: @ArshadAmeen i have updated my answer for you, now i see you are using yoast